# Benchmarks and profiling in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I see they've remove the benchmarker and profiler command line tools from Rails 4. Have they moved them into a gem? If not what are some gems you would recommend using as a substitution? I've seen ruby prof, but I want to get a feel for what else is out there too.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler

Comment: You could try [Skylight](https://www.skylight.io/) or [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) if service-based solutions are an option.

Answer (score 1):

Check Mini Profiler. It's a goodd gem to add to your Gemfile to have profilling feature added to your Rails app.

Do not expose it to production env. Only dev and test.

URL: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler